# Training E-net on human segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train a semantic-segmentation network (**E-Net**) in particular for high-quality human segmentation. For that, I have collected the "[Supervisely Person](https://hackernoon.com/releasing-supervisely-person-dataset-for-teaching-machines-to-segment-humans-1f1fc1f28469)" data-set and extracted the annotation masks using the provided API. This data-set holds high quality masks, thus I think it will provide better results in comparison to e.g. COCO data-set.

*Supervisely - Example below : original image - ground truth.*

[image]

First I want to give some details of the model. The network itself (`Enet_arch`) returns logits from the last convolution layer and probabilities which are produced through `tf.nn.sigmoid(logits,name='logits_to_softmax')`.

I am using sigmoid cross-entropy on the ground truth and the returned logits, momentum and exponential decay on the learning rate. The model instance and the training pipeline is as follows.

```
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)
    self.momentum = tf.Variable(0.9, trainable=False)

    # introducing weight decay
    #with slim.arg_scope(ENet_arg_scope(weight_decay=2e-4)):
    self.logits, self.probabilities  = Enet_arch(inputs=self.input_data, num_classes=self.num_classes, batch_size=self.batch_size) # returns logits (2d), probabilities (2d)

    #self.gt is int32 with values 0 or 1 (coming from read_tfrecords.Read_TFRecords annotation images + placeholder defined to int)
    self.gt = self.input_masks

    # self.probabilities is output of sigmoid, pixel-wise between probablities [0, 1].
    # self.predictions is filtered probabilities > 0.5 = 1 else 0
    self.predictions = tf.to_int32(self.probabilities > 0.5)

    # capture segmentation accuracy
    self.accuracy, self.accuracy_update = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=self.gt, predictions=self.predictions)

    # losses and updates
    # calculate cross entropy loss on logits
    loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=self.gt, logits=self.logits)

    # add the loss to total loss and average (?)
    self.total_loss = tf.losses.get_total_loss()

    # decay_steps = depend on the number of epochs
    self.learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(self.starter_learning_rate, global_step=self.global_step, decay_steps=123893, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True)

    #Now we can define the optimizer
    #optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate, epsilon=1e-8)
    optimizer = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(self.learning_rate, self.momentum)

    #Create the train_op.
    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=self.global_step)
```

I first tried to over-fit the model on a single image to identify the depth of details that this network can capture. To increase the output quality I resized all the images to **1080p** before feeding them to the network. On this trial I trained the network for 10K iterations and the total error reached ~30% (captured from `tf.losses.get_total_loss()` ).

The results while training **on a single image** are pretty good as you can see below.

*Supervisely - Example below : (1) Loss (2) input (before resizing) | ground truth (before resizing) | 1080p out*

[image]

[image]

Later, I tried to train on the whole data-set but the training loss produce lot of oscillations. That means that in some images the network perform well and in some other not. As a results after 743360 iterations (which is 160 epochs, since the training set holds 4646 images) I stopped training since obviously there is something wrong with the hyper-parameters selection that I made.

*Supervisely - Example below : (1) Loss (2) learning rate (3) input (before resizing) | ground truth (before resizing) | 1080p out*

[image]

[image]

[image]

On the other hand on some instances of the training set images the network produce fair (not very good though) results like below.

*Supervisely - Example below : input (before resizing) | ground truth (before resizing) | 1080p out*

[image]

Why do I have those differences on these training instances? Are there any obvious changes that I should do on the model or on the hyper-parameters? Is it possible that this model is just not suitable for this use-case (e.g. low network capacity) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: E-Net is designed to perform real-time segmentation not for accurate segmentation. So you can't expect it maintain its accuracy near boundaries. What is your use case for this model, are you trying to deploy it or are you participating in a competition ? I meant to ask if model size is a constraint for you or not  ?

Comment: Hello @papabiceps. I am trying to figure out how can I improve the model predictions, to (1) be consistent while generating segmentation masks and (2) to produce good quality results, like the ones generated while training on a single image. For now I want to find out if there is any obvious changes I can do on the hyper-parameters, or, if this is what you expect from a model like E-net. In the first case I will make some changes and try to re-train. In the second case I could replace the model architecture with e.g. DeepLabv3+ (??)  ...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem here is indeed E-net architecture. I changed the architecture with DeepLabV3 and saw a big difference in loss behaviour and performance.. even in small resolution!

[image]